# Trouble with 'Manage Products'

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, admin-panel

When we try to go to next page in `Catalog > Manage Products` the screen just freezes on `please wait`.
Any tips would be very helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Which magento version you are working?

Comment: Check the console for any javascript error